# Pivot data using t sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would really appreciate some help with a query I am having difficulty with.
Here is an example of the data:

```
DEPT  FLAG   FLAG2  FLAG3

100    A             1
100    A      B  
201    A      1   
201    1      3
300           Z
301    5
301    2      3      FG
```

I need the following results:  (distinct dept, with total count of flag, and flag2 that contains a value.)  Using the data above, the results returned should look like:

```
dept  countFlag countFlag2 countFlag3

100      2         1            1
201      2         2            0
300      0         1            0
301      2         1            1
```

100   2, 1, 1   <--- for dept 100, there are two rows that contain a value in flag column and 1 that contains a value in flag2 and 1 that contains a value in flag 3.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a pivot for this, but if you did it's worth remembering that the SQL language (any flavor) is designed such that you _will_ need to, at a minimum, know how many columns there are in the result set. Sometimes the name or the type of a column can be inferred for you, but you still need to know how many total columns you will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You donot need pivot for this. `Count(Distinct)`
 is sufficient

```
Select Dept, 
       Count(distinct Flag) as countFlag, 
       Count(distinct Flag2) as CountFlag2, 
       Count(distinct Flag3) as CountFlag3
from dept 
group by Dept
```

To include all non-null fields, use following

```
Select Dept, 
       sum(case flag when null then 0 else 1) as countFlag, 
       sum(case flag2 when null then 0 else 1)  as CountFlag2, 
       sum(case flag3 when null then 0 else 1)  as CountFlag3
from dept 
group by Dept
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very close.  However, it is only giving me the number of distinct values for a department. Ex: I need to know, in The Shoes Department, there are 425 rows with a value in flag column, and 300 rows with a value in flag2, and 0 rows with a valuein flag3.  I don't care what the value is, just that something is there.  The only thing that is distinct is the actual department name.

Comment: @AAron, Can you suggest for any item, what is expected, and what is wrong from the query result? to me it seems as per the result you returned (though not executed it)

Comment: It is almost working, (I executed the code you suggested).  The results came back with the correct departments (distinct), however, for the Flag column for dept 300 the results was 12.  It should have been over 12,000 as there were that many rows for department 300 that had a value in it, however, there were only 12 distinct values.

Comment: So, a row returned should look like  300, 12032, 11324, 0    not 300, 12, 13, 0.  I hope I explained this better.  Thanks again for your time

Comment: Updated the answer to include all fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name (DEPT INT,  
                        FLAG VARCHAR(2) 
                        ,FLAG2 VARCHAR(2),
                        FLAG3 VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO Table_Name(DEPT,  FLAG,   FLAG2,  FLAG3)
VALUES
(100,'A',null,'1'),
(100,'A','B', null),  
(201,'A','1', null),   
(201,'1','3', null),
(300, null,'Z',null),
(301,'5',null,null),
(301,'2','3','FG')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPT, COUNT(FLAG) AS FLAG, 
                COUNT(FLAG2) AS FLAG2, COUNT(FLAG3) AS FLAG3
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY DEPT
```

**Result Set**

```
DEPT    FLAG    FLAG2   FLAG3
100     2       1       1
201     2       2       0
300     0       1       0
301     2       1       1
```